# MySql - Updating a table with 1,000 rows is taking 30 seconds

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a 1000 rows in. I'm using a cursor to select each row in a loop, and update a value on each row. The table has a single primary key, and no indexes. The select and update statement are simply using the primary key ID. The operation to update all 1,000 rows is taking exactly 31 seconds with no database load. When I have a few things running over the DB, this goes up to 80+ seconds.

Can someone explain to me why with absolutely no load on the DB, 1,000 rows is taking 30+ seconds to execute?

Thanks.

Here's the code:

```
DECLARE curPlayers CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        Id,
        Turns,
        Money,
        Morale,
        MissilePower,
        TurnsPerUpdate,
        MoneyPerUpdate,
        MoralePerUpdate,
        MissilePowerPerUpdate,
        AvailableLandToPurchase,
        TS
    FROM player;

OPEN curPlayers;

FETCH curPlayers INTO
            vPlayerId,
            vPlayerTurns,
            vPlayerMoney,
            vPlayerMorale,
            vPlayerMissilePower,
            vPlayerTurnsPerUpdate,
            vPlayerMoneyPerUpdate,
            vPlayerMoralePerUpdate,
            vPlayerMissilePowerPerUpdate,
            vPlayerAvailableLandToPurchase,
            vPlayerTS;

-- ...Some simple sets on the vNewTurns variables used below...

UPDATE player SET
            Turns = vNewTurns,
            Money = vNewMoney,
            Morale = vNewMorale,
            MissilePower = vNewMissilePower,
            AvailableLandToPurchase = vNewAvailableLandToPurchase
        WHERE
            Id = vPlayerId;
```

Comment: Why are you doing it this way, instead of using a single `UPDATE` query?

Comment: If you show your code, we can almost certainly show you a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Cursors are slow. Do it in a single statement and join thr tables together to do it really fast

Comment: Because per row I have to calculate some values that I'm going to update the row with. I've commented the 'UPDATE' statement out and kept the calculations in, and the operation takes 0.03 secs.

Comment: On another server, the operation takes 0.5 secs to run with the same data. It's running on a freshly installed Windows Server 2008 R2 12GB Quad Core machine.